# C# XML Deserializing No Errors

Tags: c#, xml, object, serialization

I am currently trying to deserialize an xml string to a C# object.
I am getting no errors. Just nothing ends up in the list.

The XML is contained within a URL. I have used A xml to C# object converter to create the object.

Here is the deserialize code:

```
    public static List<Models.Betway.EventList> GetEvents()
    {
        string res = "";
        Uri myURI = new Uri("http://feeds.betway.com/events?key=CEBA7C11&keywords=horse-racing,uk-and-ireland&and=true");

        WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(myURI);
        webRequest.Timeout = 2000;

        using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
                res = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Models.Betway.EventList>), new XmlRootAttribute("EventList"));
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(res);

        List<Models.Betway.EventList> list = (List<Models.Betway.EventList>)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);

        return list;
    }
```

Here is my Object class model that I have created using an online converter:

```
 using System;
 using System.Xml.Serialization;
 using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace tf.PriceService.Core.Models.Betway
{

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Keyword")]
public class Keyword
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type_cname")]
    public string Type_cname { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "cname")]
    public string Cname { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Keywords")]
public class Keywords
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Keyword")]
    public List<Keyword> Keyword { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Outcome")]
public class Outcome
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Quicklink")]
    public string Quicklink { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "index")]
    public string Index { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type_cname")]
    public string Type_cname { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "cname")]
    public string Cname { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "starting_price")]
    public string Starting_price { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "price_num")]
    public string Price_num { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "price_den")]
    public string Price_den { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "price_dec")]
    public string Price_dec { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Market")]
public class Market
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Outcome")]
    public List<Outcome> Outcome { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "index")]
    public string Index { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type_cname")]
    public string Type_cname { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "cname")]
    public string Cname { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "handicap")]
    public string Handicap { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "situation_index")]
    public string Situation_index { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "each_way_active")]
    public string Each_way_active { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "each_way_fraction_den")]
    public string Each_way_fraction_den { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "each_way_position")]
    public string Each_way_position { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "tricast")]
    public string Tricast { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "forecast")]
    public string Forecast { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "interval_from")]
    public string Interval_from { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "interval_to")]
    public string Interval_to { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Event")]
public class Event
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Quicklink")]
    public string Quicklink { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Keywords")]
    public Keywords Keywords { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Market")]
    public List<Market> Market { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "cname")]
    public string Cname { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "start_at")]
    public string Start_at { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "home_team_cname")]
    public string Home_team_cname { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "away_team_cname")]
    public string Away_team_cname { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "started")]
    public string Started { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "EventList")]
public class EventList
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Event")]
    public List<Event> Event { get; set; }
}

}
```

As you can see I am declaring EventList as the root. But it is still not deserializing.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the XML you're deserializing? Have *you* looked at the actual text of the XML you're deserializing?

Comment: Hi yes, go to the url: http://feeds.betway.com/events?key=CEBA7C11&keywords=horse-racing,uk-and-ireland&and=true

Comment: Please add an example of the XML to your question, which reproduces the issue. Thanks.

Comment: The URL gives me a 403. I was trying to help you. "Go find it yourself" is not a very helpful answer to a request for additional information.

Comment: It deserializes 89 elements for me; what are you seeing when you say "it is still not deserializing"?

Comment: The XML is pretty big to paste on here without all the styling and rooting nests messing up

Comment: @MarcGravell I do a breakpoint on the 'return list' and the 'list' count is 0.

Comment: @ZackAntonyBucci So edit it down to a sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be deserializing a **single** `EventList` instance:

```cs
public static EventList GetEvents()
{
    /// ...
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EventList));
    // ...
    EventList list = (EventList)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);

    return list;
}
```

or alternatively, return a `List<Event>`:

```cs
public static List<Event> GetEvents()
{
    /// ...
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EventList));
    // ...
    EventList list = (EventList)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);

    return list.Event;
}
```

Also, to avoid some overhead:

```cs
using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
using (Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EventList));
    EventList list = (EventList)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Silly me that was the problem.

Comment: @ZackAntonyBucci see also the edit that avoids double-parsing the stream - you can create an `XmlReader` directly on the `Stream` to avoid overhea

Comment: @ZackAntonyBucci additional additional: avoid using the XmlSerializer constructor that takes advanced options - that can lead you to bleed assemblies (it generates a new serialization assembly **every time you do that**) - just use the `typeof(...)` constructor, as above